# How to setup geckodriver.exe file on .Net environment

Tags: .net, selenium, visual-studio-2015, automation

I was trying to run the geckodriver on VS, but I get an error:"Test Failed, OneTimeSetUp: OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException: The geckdriver.exe file does not exist in the current directory path environment variable. The driver can be downloaded at https://github.com/mozilla/geckdriver/releases.

I have already got the correct path setup with the latest version of geckodriver 1.11 but for some reason I tried troubleshooting every way I could but no luck.

Below is my test code I was trying to run the .exe file

```
FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\Users\Test\Downloads\geckodriver-v0.11.1-win64\geckodriver.exe");
        service.Port = 64444;
        service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";
        service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
        service.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true;
        IWebDriver Driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);
```

Comment: You should use NuGet in VS... it sets everything up for you. Get Selenium and the individual drivers that you want. You can see in the UI when a driver needs updating. Makes it really easy to set up and keep up-to-date.

Comment: @JeffC have the nuget package `Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver` installed and I still get this error

Answer (score 1):

One way I solved this is by Placing the drivers inside /bin/debug directory. for example  Visual Studio/projects/projname/projname/bin/debug/. Hope it helps. Cheers